# fatch only those values from case class which follow the condition

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0

```
def getAll(userid:BigInteger) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit Connection =>
      val dat = SQL("select * from id_info_user where user_id=" + userid)
      var data = dat().map(row =>
       RecordAll(row[Int]("country"),row[Int]("age"),row[Int]("gender"),row[Int]  ("school"),row[Int]("college"),row[Int]("specialization"),row[Int]("company"))).toList       
        data
    }

  }
```

Database contains six columns which have only zero or one value.
This give me the list of row values but i want only those values which are one.

Comment: Can you please provide the example data and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: user_id  country age gender school college specialization company
3    1   0  1  0   0       0             1

Comment: what result object would you like, `List(String)` for example?

Comment: the result of type listMap